# Java RMI - localhost and debugging

Tags: java, spring, localhost, rmi

I have a few services set up in the SPring config to use RMI to invoke methods. In the test environment this resolves to the `localhost`, which could potentially allow me to debug the code. Unfortunately, it simply exectures the method and returns a value. Is there a way to setup intellij to debug RMI localhost requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a problem to debug Spring RMI service? If you run it in Tomcat, just start tomcat as `catalina.sh jpda run` and in Idea create Remote Debug configuration, transport - socket, debugger mode - attach, host - localhost, port - usually 8000. That's all.

Comment: I don't quite get you. I run it local on my machine using standard java command from within intellij

Comment: So, if you run it in Idea, just debug it instead. Use not green triangle, but arrow with bug :)

Comment: Maybe in that case you need two instance of idea, first - to debug RMI service, second - to run RMI client.